# as3 save to root folder

Tags: flash, file, actionscript, air

The following script is used to save a file to the desktop:

```
    var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    ba.writeUTFBytes(xmlData);
    var fs : FileStream = new FileStream;
    var targetFile : File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath('file.xml');
    fs.open(targetFile, FileMode.WRITE);
    fs.writeBytes(ba);
    fs.close();
```

The file is loaded from the same directory as the swf file. how do I save the file in this directory. The flash file is exported as an Air app

Comment: What do you mean by *"its original directory"*?

Comment: @sch: the file being saved is loaded from the folder where the .swf file stored. I want to save in the same place

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the folder where the application is installed using `File.applicationDirectory`. However, that directory is unfortunately read-only and you can't write to it.

The appropriate place is the `File.applicationStorageDirectory` as the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#applicationDirectory) says:

> Modifying content in the application directory is a bad practice, for security reasons, and is blocked by the operating system on some platforms. If you want to store application-specific data, consider using the application storage directory (File.applicationStorageDirectory).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I ended up saving XML data with php.